# JavaScript: How to assign value of button element to another div element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set the value of a hidden div so that it equals the value of a button. I think my code below is the correct way to do it, however when I click the 'Edit' button, I do not see the value update for the div.

**Button**

```
<td>
<button id="@user.UserId" class="updateUser" value="@user.UserId">Edit</button>
</td>
```

**Div**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User_Id, new { @class = "updateUserId" })
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var updateUserId = $('div.updateUserId').val();
            $('button.updateUser').click(function () {
                updateUserId = $('button.updateUser').val();
                return updateUserId;
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you mean, you need to update the text content of the div so that it shows the value of the button when the button is clicked?

Comment: A div element does not have a Value. Only input fields have values. In a div you have innerhtml .html() or innertext .text().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here; the first is that the following line of Razor will write a hidden `<input />` element to your document (rather than a `<div>`):

```
// Produces <input type="hidden" class="updateUserId" ... />
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User_Id, new { @class = "updateUserId" })
```

This means that you'll need to update your script to select the element as an `input` (rather than as a `div`) in order to update it's value.

The second issue is with your logic in applying the button value to the hidden input during the click event. One way to achieve what you require would be to make the following tweaks:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('button.updateUser').click(function (event) {

            // Prevent possible form submission?
            event.preventDefault()

            // Obtain user value from this updateUser button
            var updateUserValue = $(this).val();

            // Select hidden input with class updateUserId and update 
            // the value to that of the button
            $('input.updateUserId').val(updateUserValue);
        });
    });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't see where you are using the `var updateUserValue`. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @MatthewWright my apologies - that was a typo on my part, just corrected the answer :)

Comment: Understood. I also went into the code and saw where to make the change.

Comment: Cool, all the best with your project :)